# How to add some headers file in VS2015

Tags: c++

I've read [visual studio 2012 adding new header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901285/visual-studio-2012-adding-new-header-file), but my problem has not been solved! Anyway, I want to add `foo.h` to my project:

```
#pragma once
void MyLDA(vector<int>, Mat_<float>, Mat&, Mat&);
```

Now, `foo.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "foo.h"

using namespace std;

auto getIndices = [](const std::vector<int>& vec, const int value)
{
//some code
}
void MyLDA(vector<int> gnd, Mat_<float> _data, Mat &eigvector, Mat &eigvalue)
{
//some code
}
```

when i build my project, i get this error:

`'vector': undeclared identifier`

`type 'int' unexpected`

`'my_project': identifier not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `#include <vector>` to use `std::vector`.  Also, [best practice is to avoid `using namespace std;` and instead write `std::vector`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)  Some also recommend that for OpenCV classes such as `Mat`.  (For what it’s worth, my own coding style is to write `std::` in front of STL classes, since there’s a lot of legacy code out there with a custom `string` or `array` class, but to write `cout` and `memcpy()` rather than things like `std::cout`, for stuff that was around long before the STL.)

There’s also a missing semicolon after the assignment of a lambda expression, which happens to look a lot like a function definition at a glance.  (@BarmakShemirani caught it, not me.)

Comment: And same for `cv::` `Mat` from OpenCV.

Comment: To simplify the answer and make it more easy to read you can remove my name, or add footnote about comments.

Comment: Updated with both of your suggestions.